# Install python package in Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-container-instances

I want to run a docker image in azure as a container. In visual studio Code everything works fine. But azure has problems with "from azure.servicebus import QueueClient" I get the errormessage:

"File "./main.py", line 11, in 
    from azure.servicebus import QueueClient, Message
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure' "

I want to unstall the package azure-servicebus
How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` that you have used to do this? You need to install `azure.servicebus` inside that container probably. Look for a proper Python Docker base image that installs modules from a `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

azure-servicebus package can be installed in the docker image using

```
pip install azure-servicebus
```

More information about package can be found at https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/

However how to install it via Dockerfile it will depends on how are you installing other dependent packages (maybe via requirements.txt file or directly installing via pip or using other packager like conda etc). If you are able to post sample Dockerfile, we could suggest changes in the file which could work immediately.